# Display month names vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-table

I have a table that displays months(Jan through Dec) in a table as follows.
This table get the values from database and it is not fixed.

```
<table width="100%" style="font-size:9px">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="14" style="text-align:center">Year: <?PHP echo $year?></th>
</tr>
<tr >
<th>Jan</th>
<th>Feb</th>
<th>Mar</th>
<th>Apr</th>
<th>May</th>
<th>Jun</th>
<th>Jul</th>
<th>Aug</th>
<th>Sep</th>
<th>Oct</th>
<th>Nov</th>
<th>Dec</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>   
<tr > 
<?PHP 
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
    $yearstart = $year."-".$i."-01";
    $yearend = $year."-".$i."-31";
    $sql="SELECT SUM(total) as totalsales_$i from salesorder where user_id=7 and created  BETWEEN '$yearstart' AND '$yearend' ";
    $res = $db->sql_query($sql);
    $row =  $db->sql_fetchrow($res);
    $total = $total + $row['totalsales_'.$i];
?>
<td style="width: 96px; text-align:right">
<?PHP if ($row['totalsales_'.$i] !='' ) 
    echo "$".number_format($row['totalsales_'.$i],2);
  else     
    echo "<font color=#c2c2c2>$0.00</font>";?>
 </td>
<?PHP //for ?> 
<td style="text-align:right"><?PHP echo "$".number_format($total,2) ;?></td>
</tr>                                       
</tbody></table>

OUTPUT:
    Jan    feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec    Total
    $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0
    $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0
    $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0     $0
    ...
    ...
```

But what I need is how to display the table vertically, as follows

```
                2011    2012    2013    ...

    Jan         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    feb         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    Mar         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    Apr         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    May         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    Jun         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    Jul         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    Aug         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    Sep         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    Oct         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    Nov         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    Dec         $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
    Total       $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
```

I tried a few different ways, but no luck. I wish I could show you some code here about what I tried, but I realy don't have anthing to show.

Does anyone have any idea how to display this table vetically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , you may want to stop executing 12<sup>n</sup> queries and get all info with one go and power of aggregation mechanism in MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(created) as `Y`, 
    MONTH(created) AS `M`, 
    SUM(total) AS `SUM` 
FROM 
    salesorder
WHERE
    user_id = 7
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(created), 
    MONTH(created) 
WITH ROLLUP
```

this will result in resultset like this:

```
Y    | M    | SUM
2011 | 10   | 20.00
2011 | 11   | 10.00
2011 | 12   | 5.00
2011 | NULL | 35.00     // M == NULL -> sum for this year
2012 | 1    | 7.00
2012 | 2    | 7.00
2012 | NULL | 14.00
NULL | NULL | 49.00     // M & Y == NULL -> sum for whole resultset
```

So you will have sum for individual months in every row, sum for every year if `M` column is null and sum for whole result in the last row (you can discard it, if you don't need it)

Now you have to create other array that will be easier to iterate while adding rows into your table. I would suggest it to look like this:

```
$tableRows = array(
    0 => array( // 0 will be for sum from each year
             2011 => 0,
             2012 => 0
    ),
    1 => array( // January
             2011 => 0
    ...
);
```

I don't know what class are you using to interact with database, so let me assume there is some method that allows to fetch associative array from resultset

```
$years = array();
while($dbRow = $res->fetchAssoc()){
    $y = intval($dbRow['Y']);
    if($y){
        $m = intval($dbRow['M']);
        $tableRow[$m][$y] = $dbRow['SUM'];
    }    
}
$allYears = array_keys($tableRows[0]); // get all years we have
```

Finally you can present it in your table:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Month</th>
       <?php foreach($allYears as $year): ?>
       <th><?=$year?></th>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
     </tr>
   <thead>
   <tfoot>
   <? foreach($tableRows as $month => $years): ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?=$month?></td>
   <?php foreach($allYears as $y): ?>
      <td><?=$years[$y]?></td>
   <?php endforeach; 
   if(!$month): ?>
   </tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>
   <?php else: ?>
   </tr>
   <?php endif;
   endforeach; ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

what needs to be corrected is to display month name and `Total` instead of numbers in first column

Answer (score 2):

You can first obtain the data from the database and store it in an accessible way into an array, like:

```
$array[$year][$monthOrTotal] = $value;
```

Then you can iterate over that array to output your table in every direction you like:

```
$cols = array('2011', '2012', '2013');
$rows = explode(',', 'Jan,feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Total');

echo '<table>', '<tr>', '<th></th>';
foreach($cols as $col)
{
   echo '<th>', $col, '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    echo '<tr>', '<th>', $row, '</th>';
    foreach($cols as $col)
    {
        echo '<td>', $array[$col][$row], '</td>';
    }
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

(Untested code warning)

This done you have separated the part where you obtain the data from your store and the output of it. That's generally advisable because you don't mix problems with the output logic with obtaining the data. This reduces problems then.